# Set font of custom ListActivity in Android

Tags: android, fonts, listactivity

I have a custom ListActivity that acts as a multiple choice question, and I am trying to change the font of the items in the list. Here's what I have...

```
public class MultipleChoiceActivity extends ListActivity {

private TextView questionView;
private String[] items = { "a", "b", "c", "d" };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //do some stuff like populate items array from db

    setContentView(R.layout.multichoice_activity);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_list_item, items));
    questionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    Typeface typeFace=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Schalk.ttf");
    questionView.setText(question);
    questionView.setTypeface(typeFace);
}

public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    userAnswer = position + 1;
}
```

So I have been able to set the TextView named "question" with the correct font from my assets, but I haven't been able to use that asset to set it for the elements in the list. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `TypeFace` for each specific view you want. Usually this means, at a bare minimum, you need to set the `TypeFace` for each view *in the adapter* as opposed to the `ListView` itself.